# Playstation 4 controller doesnt work

Tags: controllers

[image] as it shows in the picture this white light appears then it turns off it happens everytime i try to use ps4 menu controller i tried to initialize the ps4 before this happened since it had some issue with always disconnected when it was plugged every second it happened the disconnection after this i tried reset on the controller and didnt work all this while it is plugged on the ps4 hopefully someone can help if a video is needed ill be glad to share it

Answer (score -1):

Why not just purchase a new controller?

Maybe try inserting a charging wire in the PS4 connect it to your controller and use it like that.

If that doesn't work you can either take it to maybe a local game store to fix it or take the cover off and rearrange all the parts correctly.

Comment: *Why not just purchase a new controller?* -> While this is a viable option, controllers can be expensive

Comment: Yes they can be. However there are some for prices around £30 and if even that is too much, prices for fixing controllers are probably even less. If you do not want to pay you can simply remove all parts of the controller and re arrange them with a video for assistance.

Comment: I cant repair them or buy a new one here all is expensive around $7000 thanks for the answer but and here if they break controller even more there isnt a refund its all risky.that is why i asked in first place for an easy fix since both of my controllers do the same